# BPMN, does an output artifact need input?

Tags: bpmn, artifacts

Hello fellow Overflowians!

I am currently modelling a ticket machine at a trainstation, and I have added a few output artifacts. For example, I have them at print ticket and print receipt. My question is, do I need to add input somewhere in the model?

[image]

(These are the input and output artifacts I am referring to)

Logically it seems to me that I would need input somewhere, because how else could there be output? At the same time however, a ticket machine has options that you choose on a touchscreen, does that really count as input?

Grateful for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to have a start event for your bpmn. It may be  without any data or not depending on your requirement. There are differant types of start events. Choose the correct one.Refer [1] and [2] on basics.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS350/BPMN+Basics
[2] - https://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2016/03/tutorial-how-to-model-your-business-processes-with-wso2-business-process-server/#step2